# Classes don't match between main SWF and runtime loaded SWF from another domain

Tags: actionscript-3, class, flash, cross-domain

I load an external SWF. The **external SWF** has an embedded **DisplayObject** *(getChildAt(0))* and I get an instance of its **Class** with the following code:

```
    public function getEmbedded():* {
        var _class:Class = loaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition(getQualifiedClassName(getChildAt(0))) as Class;
        return new _class();
    }
```

So far so good. If the **main SWF** (which loads the above external SWF) and the **external SWF** are in the same domain (local or online), the classes of the **main** and **external** SWF **match**:

E.g. say I have embedded a **fanlib.tween.TPlayer** object in the external SWF. In the main SWF I do:

```
var clip3:fanlib.tween.TPlayer = externalSwf.getEmbedded();
```

and it works fine.

**BUT!!!**

**If the external SWF is loaded from another domain, the classes don't match!!!**

I get errors like this:

> [Fault] exception, information=TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion
>   failed: cannot convert fanlib.tween::TPlayer@2563221 to
>   fanlib.tween.TPlayer.

This is not a problem with *crossDomain*, I have set the *XML* file and *Security context* correctly and the external SWF loads with **no security errors**. The problems occur when trying to cast the embedded class to a main object.

Can this be solved in any way???

Comment: Are you setting a LoaderContext on your Loader object when loading the child swf? See - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html#applicationDomain

Comment: How would that help? The embedded class inherits a class of the main swf. Main casts it as 'TPlayer', but the embedded class is a descendant of 'TPlayer'..?

Comment: Well as you state it works in same domain, so I would suggest reading that article as it lists various scenarios of classes being used in both parent and child relationships when used with different Loader Contexts.

Answer (score 2):

you can get your code working using
`var clip3:* = externalSwf.getEmbedded();`
and if you want to keep your code warnings free use an `interface`
`var clip3: TplayerInterface = externalSwf.getEmbedded() as TplayerInterface;`

Comment: Guess what, the interfaces don't match either :-)